# Why does Handsontable display the headers like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handsontable

[image]

What I did is just

```
$('#dataTable').handsontable(
                {rows: 2, cols: 1, colHeaders: ['Parameter'], minSpareRows: 1}
                );
```

Why the header is displaying like 1 and a part below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to quickly reproduce the issue in [this fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bkm04z1m/). Once this was reproduced I realized that your issue probably is forgetting to include the style sheet. I updated and included this missing style sheet and ended up with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkm04z1m/3/) (that works). The style include would look something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://handsontable.com/dist/jquery.handsontable.full.css">
```

Of course, you could download the css file and include it from a relative path and that would also work. Hope that puts you on the right track. Best of luck!

Per the comments below - the main issue here could be not that the style isn't included but that it has been overridden. Without getting too much into the weeds of the handson table it appears that there is an actual data table then the editing cells are placed on top of that (via `position: absolute`). In order to style the editing cells use the appropriate `.ht_clone` classes. In order to style the "static" table, use the `.ht_master` class. The following code shows how to do that:

```
/* hide the static table header */
.ht_master th {
    display: none;
}

/* hide the editing for the header ("clone_top") */
.ht_clone_top {
    display: none;
}
```

See this working in a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bkm04z1m/7/). Hope that helps!

Comment: I think your link solved the problem. But to get deeper, i believe handsontable has done some kind of shadow table under the active one. How to remove that shadow table?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to do this? I am guessing that there is a good deal of code in handsontable that counts on this "shadow copy".

Comment: I actually don't mind, just that I inherit a bunch of css for handsontable from another person. If I use your css, it is fine,but if I load that person's css, it is messed up. So I am wondering which part in css is controlling this?

Comment: I updated your http://jsfiddle.net/bkm04z1m/6/. Basically, if I add that css, then it breaks

Comment: I can't solve every issue but I did provide some information on how to style the table in an update to my answer. By the way the "correct" way to style the table is something like this: http://handsontable.com/demo/conditional.html

Answer (score 2):

I think this 
.ht_clone_top {
    display: none;
} can solve the misalignment, however, it does not allow sorting afterwards...If you click the column header, it does not sort...